# angular 5 how to manage multiple projects?

Tags: structure, project, angular5

there are some projects in dev folder, UI - angular 5 apps:

```
dev folder
    project1.UI folder
    project1.Server folder
    project2.UI folder
    project2.server folder
```

At the begining was only project1:

```
project1 folder
src
    app
    shared
         components
         services
         utils
    package.json
```

Now need to create project2. Project2 should be separated, but it have some common stuff with project1 - some components, services, utils and also some packages from npm. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Nrwl Extensions for Angular](https://nrwl.io/nx) by Viktor Savkin, Jeff Cross and few others (core members of Angular) which is a toolkit for enterprise angular apps. It provides good support for managing multiple Angular projects using mono repo.